# Unable to retrieve number before incoming call in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am able to retrieve incoming call number in other version of android  but unable to retrieve incoming call number in `marshmallow android`

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext=context;
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    intentStart = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intentStart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    mContext.startActivity(intentStart);
                }

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

    }}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

With minor modifications, your code worked fine on my Nexus 6 using MRA58K. I removed line 2 and used `context` instead of `mContext`. I also declared a local intent on line 13.

Comment: In this code Toast does not showing with number when when I my phone get a call

Answer (score 0):

It's happens when application don't have PHONE permission.
How it's works - http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/index.html#permission-groups