# Unable to print incoming caller number to logcat in android marshmallow

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-logcat

Manifest XML:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LeadActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lead"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />


    </application>
```

Here is my phonestatelistener code :

```
private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        LeadActivity la = new LeadActivity();
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            // Is called whenever there is a change in call state
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    phone_number=incomingNumber;
                    Log.d("Hub","CallStateListener Ringing IncomingNumber:"+ incomingNumber);
                    la.setContactNo(phone_number);
                    checkIt = 1;
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    checkIt = 0;
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if (checkIt == 1) {
                        Log.d("Hub","Call Disconnected:"+ incomingNumber);
                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),LeadActivity.class);
                       // la.setContactNo(phone_number);
                        getBaseContext().startActivity(i); // service that sends the SMS
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

This is my Main activity code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Hub","Main Activity Started");
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);


        tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE))
        {
            Log.d("ConvergeHub","Already permitted");

        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("ConvergeHub","Need permission");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        }
    }
    if(MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        Log.d("ConvergeHub","PERMISSION_GRANTED");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("ConvergeHub","PERMISSION_DENIED");
    }
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://xxxx.xxxxxx.com/");


    }
```

and the log gets printed like this

> 07-01 18:58:06.962 6876-6876/com.xxx.xxx D/Hub: CallStateListener Ringing IncomingNumber:
>
> 07-01 18:58:16.921 6876-6876/com.xxx.xxx D/Hub: Call Received:

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491585/unable-to-retrieve-number-before-incoming-call-in-marshmallow) that does not have a proper or accepted solution .
I have also added code for runtime permission. There is a popup while launching the app where I allow the app to manage phone calls. But the result is same as before.
Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong ? Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked for runtime permission?

> [Requesting Permissions at Runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Do I have to put these permissions in the onCallStateChanged() method ? Or somewhere else ?

Comment: Refer to this link https://github.com/sagarjogadia28/PermissionSample. It has the implementation of both single and multiple permissions.

Comment: I added the runtime permissions but still didn't work